# /dev/random entropy on readonly file system

Tags: devices, random

My hostapd works very well on my raspberry Pi3. But if I put root filesystem in readonly, it does not work. I have put some folders like /var/run and /tmp in a ramdisk filesystem.

I have seen something in log files when the root filesystem is readonly:

```
random: Cannot read from /dev/random: Resource temporarily unavailable
random: Got 0/20 bytes from /dev/random
random: Only 0/20 bytes of strong random data available from /dev/random
random: Not enough entropy pool available for secure operations
```

So I think something is wrong with /dev/random when the root filesystem is in readonly mode.

What should I do to fix that ?

-- Edit --
Here is the output of ls -l /dev/random:

```
crw-rw-rw- 1 root root 1, 8 nov.  12 16:17 /dev/random
```

Comment: Can you add the output of `ls -l /dev/random` (to your question, not as a response comment)?

Comment: Do you have the hardware random number generator enabled?  If no, you might take a look at: https://www.nico-maas.de/?p=1562  You'll want to install and configure package `rng-tools`.

Comment: It is a raspberry pi3 so i do not know if there is an hardware random number genrator...

Comment: Raspberry pi 3 has a RNG.

Comment: Okay so what should i do to make it work ?

Comment: Do you have some specific question about the procedure described in the link that I provided in an earlier comment?